# Replacing a single quote with two single quotes in a two-way bound textbox

Tags: c#

I have a WPF application that has a text box with a two-way binding. The XAML code looks like this:

```
<TextBox materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="Name*" materialDesign:HintAssist.HintOpacity="10" materialDesign:HintAssist.Background="White" materialDesign:ValidationAssist.Background="White" materialDesign:HintAssist.Foreground="#FF002655" Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignOutlinedTextFieldTextBox}" x:Name="txtboxFirstName" Width="260" TextChanged="txtboxFirstName_TextChanged">
<Binding Path="FirstName" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" Mode="TwoWay" Source="{StaticResource MyConfigs}">
    <Binding.ValidationRules>
        <local:TextBoxValidation ValidatesOnTargetUpdated="True"/>
    </Binding.ValidationRules>
</Binding>
</TextBox>
```

And the code behind looks like this:

```
private void txtboxFirstName_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    MyConfigs.FirstName = txtboxFirstName.Text;
    ((MainWindow)System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow).ValidIntroductionConfigs();
}
```

I am trying to do the following here:

1. If the user enters a single quote `'` here, it should be replaced with `''` in the MyConfigs.FirstName because otherwise it causes issues in SQL queries.
2. When the app is loaded up it takes up the value from the `MyConfigs.FirstName` configuration. And if that contains `''`, it should display them as `'`.

For example: I enter `O'Brian` here. Now, `O'Brian` should be saved as `O''Brian` in `MyConfigs.FirstName` however, when I load it up, it should display `O'Brian` which is the real name.

When I did this, it just kept on replacing `'` with `''` and made it something like `O''''''Brian`. It kept on going so I just kept on getting more single quotes.

```
private void txtboxFirstName_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (txtboxFirstName.Text.Contains("'"))
    {
        MyConfigs.FirstName = txtboxFirstName.Text.Replace("'", "''");
    }
    if (MyConfigs.FirstName.Contains("''"))
    {
        txtboxFirstName.Text = MyConfigs.FirstName.Replace("'", "''");
    }
    MyConfigs.FirstName = txtboxFirstName.Text;
    ((MainWindow)System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow).ValidIntroductionConfigs();
}
```

Comment: From a design point of view there is more than just `'` that could screw up any SQL queries. You should instead sanitize ALL the inputs when building the query. Your SQL provider should have some kind of `sanitize` function that you can use when building the queries. Sorry this does not answer your question directly.

Comment: @RedX this is a *questionable* suggestion. Not really sure why you would recommend that over properly using parametrized queries. Some explanation why you think you approach is better would be useful for users, especially who claim to be new to SO.

Comment: Agree with Alexei - use parameters. Don't build your SQL by concatenating strings and use parameters to keep code and data separate and you'll reap benefits (such as not having to turn non-string data into strings just to force the database to have to re-parse the data back to the correct data type)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Sorry bad wording on my side. I meant parameterized as those will take proper action to sanitize the parameters. I wish I could amend my comment to use the proper wording.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you did not correctly set the Replace arguments for the second replacement. You should switch it to this:

```
txtboxFirstName.Text = MyConfigs.FirstName.Replace("''", "'");
```

Otherwise **every** ' in MyConfigs.FirstName will be replaced by ''. That's why you get O''''Brian output.